# How to sum a dynamic range in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have been trying to sum a range that can change based on certain criteria. Here is the formula that works:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&B1&":A"&B2))
```

However, what if I was not able to select the entire A coloumn? When I change the formula to the rows I want, it returns 0. The range I want is A1:A4.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("A1"&B1&":A4"&B2))
```

Why does the first formula work but the second not?

Thanks,

G

Comment: The second formula works for me. What Office version are you using?

Comment: If you want a specific range why the INDIRECT(): `=SUM(A1:A4)`?

Comment: Because you have `A1` and `A4` hardcoded in the second formula.  Remove the numbers (so that it is identical to your first formula), and then define your row numbers using the cell references (`B1` and `B2`) in the formula.  `B1` would need to be set to `1` and `B2` would need to be set to `4` for the formula to work properly.  Those cells are probably blank currently.

Comment: The second formula is no working and returning `0` because you don't have any values in the range `A11:A44`. You are getting that from concatenate `"A1"&B1&":A4"&B2` = `"A1"&1&":A4"&4 ` = `A11:A44`.